# How to manipulate text to use in time math

Tags: php

I would like to manipulate the following string

`$str = "3 year 2 month week day 2 hour 12 minute 60 second";`

to change none-numeric such `week` to `1 week` and `day` to `1 day` and then add minus sign to all so the string be like

`$str = "-3 year -2 month -1 week -1 day -2 hour -12 minute -60 second";`

how to achieve this !

Another example

```
$str = "2 year month day";
```

to

```
$str = "-2 year -1 month -1 day";
```

Comment: show us what did you try to solve it ?

Comment: i've used `explode()` then alter each one using `str_replace()` but all ways failed :(

Comment: what kind of sentences you can have ? or only you will have the same one like that ?

Comment: i would like to change any date that has no numeric for example if it only `day` it changed to `1 day` and so on ... second is to add negative sign to all numbers :) i thought it would be easy but after many trys is think it is very difficult to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here, better use **regexp substitution**.

**1. First, add a 1 to each words not preceded by a figure ([0-9]):**

```
$str = preg_replace("/(^|[^0-9]\s)([A-Z])/i", "$1 1 $2", $str);
```

Details:

- **`(^|[^0-9]\s)([A-Z])`**: **retrieve** and **capture** (since it's enclosed by `()`) all letter (`([A-Z])`) preceded by a beginning of line (`^`) or a figure followed a blank space (`[^0-9]\s`), which is catpured too ; this is how we could detect a word not preceeded by a numeric;
- **`/i`**: perform a case insensitive retrieving (no need to write **[A-Za-z]**) 
  Then add a minus before a sequence of figures;
- **`"$1 1 $2"`**: write the captured figure (`$1`), a space, a 1 figure and the letter sequence (`$2`)

**2. Then, add the minus `-` before all the numeric values**

```
$str = preg_replace("/[0-9]+/", "-$0", $str);
```

Here, `$0` contains the whole matched string.

Working example:

```
$str = "year 2 month week day 2 hour 12 minute 60 second";
echo $str . "<br/>";
$str = preg_replace("/(^|[^0-9]\s)([A-Z])/i", "$1 1 $2", $str);
echo $str . "<br/>";
$str = preg_replace("/[0-9]+/", "-$0", $str);
echo $str . "<br/>";
```

Output:

```
year 2 month week day 2 hour 12 minute 60 second
1 year 2 month 1 week 1 day 2 hour 12 minute 60 second
-1 year -2 month -1 week -1 day -2 hour -12 minute -60 second
```

**Bonus: alternate version with one call:**

```
$str = "year 2 month week day 2 hour 12 minute 60 second";
$patterns = array("/(^|[^0-9]\s)([A-Z])/i", "/[0-9]+/");
$replacements = array("$1 1 $2", "-$0");
$str = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $str);
echo $str . "<br/>";
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect and very helpful .. I've learn a lot from this amazing answer ~ thanks a lot.

Comment: still not cover all possibilies for example : `$str = "year";` gives `year` while it should be `-1 year`.

Comment: @IsabelleJacob, fixed the issue of some others. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here’s one approach that splits this into parts at the space character, and then checks each individual part for whether it was numeric or not, and also “looks back” to the previous part, to determine whether it’s one of those cases where we only have the “unit” without any value before it.

Please note that this will only work with the very strict format you have shown; missing spaces or stuff like that might make it break.

```
<?php

$str = "3 year 2 month week day 2 hour 12 minute 60 second";

$parts = explode(' ', $str); // split at space
$result = [];
$prevPartWasNum = false; // flag to remember if the previous part was numeric or not
foreach($parts as $part) {
  if(is_numeric($part)) { // if the part is numeric, we need to check whether to add -
    $result[] = ($part < 0 ? '' : '-') . $part;
    $prevPartWasNum = true;
  }
  else {
    if($prevPartWasNum) { // if the previous part was nummeric, we can add straight away
      $result[] = $part;
    }
    else { // otherwise we have to introduce the additional -1
      $result[] = '-1 ' . $part;
    }
    $prevPartWasNum = false;
  }
}
echo implode(' ', $result);
```

Comment: this is perfect, it cover all possibilities .. best answer .. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example :

```
$keywords = array('year','week','month','day','hour','minute','second');

$str = "3 year 2 month week day 2 hour 12 minute 60 second";
$str = str_replace(' ', '', $str);

foreach($keywords as $keyword){
    if($pos=strpos($str,$keyword)){
        if(is_numeric($str[$pos-1]) ==0){
            $str= substr($str, 0 ,$pos ).'1'.substr($str,$pos,strlen($str));
        }
    }
}



$str = preg_replace('([0-9]+)' , ' -$0 ',$str);
echo $str;
```

The result:

```
 -3 year -2 month -1 week -1 day -2 hour -12 minute -60 second
```